Why is Context Menu Data Context is null on the first opening but is what is expected on the next opening in WPF?
So when the program starts and I right-click the ListViewItem the context menu is shown but its DataContext is not the object linked to the ListViewItem that I clicked. That is why this binding does not work and the converter's Convert method not fired:
<Image>
       <Image.Source>
              <Binding
               Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource RealTime}" />
        </Image.Source>
</Image>

But when I close the ContextMenu and open it again suddenly eerything works fine. But why not right after the start of the program?
I have this ListView:
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListView" Margin="0,0,0,10"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ProcessInfos}"
                  Background="#1a1a1a" Foreground="#e0e0e0"
                  BorderBrush="#333333" BorderThickness="1"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProcessInfo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  FontSize="15">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomHeader" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Grid MinWidth="50" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="40">
                        <TextBlock Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" TextAlignment="Center"
                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" Width="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

                <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                    <Style.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#2b2b2b" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e0e0e0" />
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                    </Style.Setters>


                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3a3a3a" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#4a4a4a" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e0e0e0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=models:ProcessInfo}">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Border>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Width="20" Height="20" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Bindin gProcess.ProcessName}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Template="{StaticResource CustomHeader}" Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                                  BorderThickness="0" Tag="Process Name" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Process.Id}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Template="{StaticResource CustomHeader}" Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                                  BorderThickness="0" Tag="PID" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="180"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MemoryUsage}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Template="{StaticResource CustomHeader}" Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                                  BorderThickness="0" Tag="Memory Usage" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="180"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CpuUsage}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Template="{StaticResource CustomHeader}" Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                                  BorderThickness="0" Tag="CPU Usage" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="120"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Process.Threads.Count}">
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Template="{StaticResource CustomHeader}" Margin="-3,0,0,0"
                                                  BorderThickness="0" Tag="Thread Count" />
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

And this ContextMenu of the ListViewItem:
<ContextMenu x:Key="MenuItemContextMenu" Opened="ListViewItem_ContextMenuOpening" Background="#1e1e1e" Foreground="#e0e0e0" BorderBrush="#4a4a4a"
                     d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance models:ProcessInfo}">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>

                <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="0" Padding="25 10">
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" />
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                              Width="5"
                                              Height="5"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 -10 0" />
                            <Popup x:Name="SubMenuPopup" Placement="Right"
                                   IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" Focusable="False"
                                   PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Border Background="#1e1e1e" BorderBrush="#4a4a4a"
                                        BorderThickness="1">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>

                <!-- Style for MenuItems -->
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e0e0e0" />
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}">
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333333" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333333" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>

                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="RealTime">RealTime</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>
                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="High">High</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>
                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="AboveNormal">AboveNormal</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>
                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="Normal">Normal</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>
                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="BelowNormal">BelowNormal</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>
                <diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass x:Key="Low">Idle</diagnostics:ProcessPriorityClass>

                <converters:PriorityToIconConverter x:Key="PriorityToIconConverter" />

            </ContextMenu.Resources>

            <!-- Set Affinity -->
            <MenuItem Header="Set affinity" />

            <!-- Set Priority with Submenu -->
            <MenuItem Header="Set priority" x:Name="MenuItem">
                <MenuItem Header="Realtime" CommandParameter="{StaticResource RealTime}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource RealTime}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="High" CommandParameter="{StaticResource High}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource High}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Above Normal" CommandParameter="{StaticResource AboveNormal}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource AboveNormal}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Normal" CommandParameter="{StaticResource Normal}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource Normal}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Below Normal" CommandParameter="{StaticResource BelowNormal}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource BelowNormal}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Low" CommandParameter="{StaticResource Low}">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image>
                            <Image.Source>
                                <Binding
                                    Path="Process" Converter="{StaticResource PriorityToIconConverter}"
                                    ConverterParameter="{StaticResource Low}" />
                            </Image.Source>
                        </Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>

        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#e0e0e0" />
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemContextMenu}" />
            <!-- Hover and Selected States -->
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#333333" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ffffff" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

ViewModel:
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using TaskManagerPlusPlus.Dialogs;
using TaskManagerPlusPlus.Models;
using TaskManagerPlusPlus.Services;
using TaskManagerPlusPlus.Views;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace TaskManagerPlusPlus.ViewModels;

public partial class TasksViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly IProcessInfosManager _processInfosManager;
    [ObservableProperty] private ProcessInfosCollection _processInfos = [];
    [ObservableProperty] private ProcessInfo? _selectedProcessInfo;

    public TasksViewModel(IProcessInfosManager processInfosManager)
    {
        _processInfosManager = processInfosManager;
        
        RefreshProcesses();

        var timer = new Timer(1000)
        {
            AutoReset = true
        };

        timer.Elapsed += (_, _) => { RefreshProcesses(); };

        timer.Start();
    }

    private void RefreshProcesses()
    {
        var selectedProcessInfoProcessId = SelectedProcessInfo?.Process.Id;
        try
        {
            var processInfos = _processInfosManager.GetProcessInfos();

            ProcessInfos.Clear();
            foreach (var processInfo in processInfos)
            {
                ProcessInfos.Add(processInfo);
            }

            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                ProcessInfos.NotifyCollectionChanged();
                SelectedProcessInfo = ProcessInfos.FirstOrDefault(processInfo =>
                    processInfo.Process.Id == selectedProcessInfoProcessId);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void KillProcess()
    {
        SelectedProcessInfo?.Process.Kill();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void StartProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            var startProcessDialog = new StartProcessDialog();
            var showDialog = startProcessDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (showDialog.HasValue && showDialog.Value)
            {
                var process = new Process
                {
                    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(startProcessDialog.TaskLocation)
                    {
                        ErrorDialog = true
                    }
                };
                process.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Process cannot be started.", "Process startup failure", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
}

I have tried this:
public TasksView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var timer = new Timer(2000) { AutoReset = true };

        

        timer.Elapsed += (_, _) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var listViewItem = (ListViewItem)ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListView.Items[0]);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    var contextMenu = listViewItem.ContextMenu!;
                    var menuItem = (MenuItem)((MenuItem)contextMenu.Items[1]!).Items[3]!;
                    Console.WriteLine(contextMenu.DataContext == null);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        };

        timer.Start();
    }

It showed that when the program started the data context is null but then after closing and opening again it shows that it is not null.
I also tried this:
private void TasksView_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listViewItem = (ListViewItem)ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ListView.Items[0]);

        var contextMenu = listViewItem.ContextMenu!;
        contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        contextMenu.IsOpen = false;
    }

Nothing worked.

Just use data binding:
<ContextMenu ...
    DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

In case you would have to set this Binding on multiple ContextMenus, declare an appropriate Setter in a global Style like
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="DataContext"
                Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


thanks this looks like a good solution but I have already found a solution which is easier but you know it involves some code behind. Bindings are just better, thanks

I wouldn't say that attaching a ContextMenuOpening handler is actually easier.

private void ListViewItem_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ContextMenu contextMenu &&
        contextMenu.PlacementTarget is FrameworkElement placementTarget)
    {
        contextMenu.DataContext = placementTarget.DataContext;
    }
}



You may also use data binding, similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438949/1136211

Like this: <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

ContextMenu behaves a bit wildly with its DataContext when you tries to use one ContextMenu instance for multiple potential targets.
A good fix for the issue is to set ContextMenu's DataContext when it's opening. Using PlacementTarget as a source of right DataContext is a good idea, so your solution is a good one.
Another solution is to change DataContext when PlacementTarget changes. You can use a custom ContextMenu class, so you won't have to deal with event handlers.
public class SharedContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    private readonly DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler _elementDataContextChanged;

    static SharedContextMenu()
    {
        PlacementTargetProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            forType: typeof(SharedContextMenu),
            typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                propertyChangedCallback: PlacementTargetChanged));
    }

    public SharedContextMenu()
    {
        _elementDataContextChanged = ElementDataContextChanged;
    }

    private static void PlacementTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (SharedContextMenu)d;

        var oldElement = e.OldValue as FrameworkElement;
        if (oldElement != null)
        {
            oldElement.DataContextChanged -= self._elementDataContextChanged;
        }

        var newElement = e.NewValue as FrameworkElement;
        if (newElement != null)
        {
            self.DataContext = newElement.DataContext;
            newElement.DataContextChanged += self._elementDataContextChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            self.DataContext = null;
        }
    }

    private void ElementDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContext = e.NewValue;
    }
}

Replace plain <ContextMenu> with this one and everything should just work.

You don't need a custom ContextMenu. With data binding (as shown in the comment to the other answer), the ContextMenu's DataContext is updated when either the PlacementTarget or the PlacementTarget's DataContext changes.

I tried the solution with data binding a long time ago, but the result was not satisfying. In some cases binding was too slow. After all DispatcherPriority.DataBind is not the highest one. Also with custom class I don't have to remember about such bindings, because everything just works as expected.

That makes no sense to me. Using a complicated custom control instead of a straightforward binding expression? No sure what exactly you would have to remember in addition to the usual binding syntax. And "binding was too slow" is not exactly a precise problem statement, especially when it was "long ago".

"Too slow" means that some other bindings was able to complain about null DataContext before DataContext's binding was resolved. About using straightforward bindings: if I have to choose between using a straightforward binding or not using anything at all then I choose to don't use anything at all. You have to write the same binding in every instance of ContextMenu, writing a simple custom control is done only once.

You could establish the binding in a Setter for the DataContext property in a global ContextMenu Style.
